# Avatar picture does not display when using get_avatar

Tags: bbpress, avatar, gravatar

I'm using WordPress with bbPress and Gravatar for user avatars. I want to display the user's avatar next to their topic. I'm using:

```
echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 32 );
```

Which get's me this:

[image]

I know that my author image is set because I set it myself.

Comment: Are you working with bbPress or something? If so, you should update your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The [**`get_avatar`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar) function is a [**pluggable function**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions) with it's first parameter being either the user's ID or email.

You're using **get_avatar** with [**`get_the_author_meta('ID')`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/) which should give you the ID of the current user within the Loop.

> ### [From the Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/#more-information)
>
> If used within [**The Loop**](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), the user ID need not be specified, it
>   defaults to current post author. A user ID must be specified if used
>   outside [**The Loop**](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

```
get_the_author_meta( string $field = '', int $user_id = false )
```

So it would be redundant using [**`get_avatar`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar) with [**`get_the_author_meta('ID')`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/), you can just specify the ID directly:

```
echo get_avatar( USER_ID, 32 );
```

Comment: thank you Tunji , it kinda fixed the problem but still ,it shows the default avatar picture for all users

Comment: You have to make sure you're passing the right user_id for each user

Comment: @ouqasmohamed I'm wondering if you should be using bbpress specific functions here: `get_avatar( bbp_get_topic_author_id( $topic_id ), $size )`

Comment: @ouqasmohamed Or even better: `bbp_get_topic_author_avatar` https://bproots.bbroots.com/reference/functions/bbp_get_topic_author_avatar/

Comment: @jami0821 now with bbp_get_topic_author_avatar() , i get in result the post_id not the avatar, here is the code i'm using inside the loop 
bbp_get_topic_author_avatar ( bbp_topic_id() , 40 );

Comment: I think you might be using the incorrect topic id function: `<?php echo bbp_get_topic_author_avatar( bbp_get_topic_id(), 40); ?>`

Comment: @jami0821  
i used this line <?php echo bbp_get_topic_author_avatar( bbp_get_topic_id(), 40); ?> it shows the image i used in my question , the default avatar image for all users